# Accessing a 3D array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a char*** and I dynamically allocate some memory to it. However, when I try to assign some values to it, I get segmentation fault. The size I am using is not too big. It works when I create char[768][1024][3] but doesn't work when I add this dynamically with same exact values. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
pic = new char**[height];
    for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        pic[i] == new char*[width];
        for(int j = 0; j< width; j++)
        {
            pic[i][j] == new char[3];
        }
    }
    pic[0][0][0] = 'a';//seg fault here
    exit(1);
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  LOL not yet. I have to get past this segmentation fault

Comment: Why not use nested `std::vector`'s? Far easier to use.

Comment: It is simple. You do know the difference between `==` and `=`? I assume any compiler with all warnings on (as they *always* should be) would mention this. For example Visual C++: warning C4553: '==': operator has no effect; did you intend '='?

Comment: Well, because we have to convert the given code into threads. We cannot use vectors or any other stuff. Just have to use the given code and add threads to it. I have done the hard bit but got stuck on this bit which was supposed to be easy!

Comment: You can well use something like a `std::vector<std::thread>`, `std::thread`supports move construction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pic[i] == new char*[width];` -> Why is there a `==` comparison instead of `=` assignment ?

Similarly for `pic[i][j] == new char[3];` -> a comparison is being done and no assignment.

Comment: AH damn no how can I miss it. Thanks any way :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
pic = new char[height * width * 3];
```

Access `pic[i][j][k]` using:

```
pic[i * width + j * 3 + k]
```